# EF Code First not working on deploy hosting

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, code-first

I've an application using MVC and Code First for persistence.

Everything works fine in my development, but when I'm uploading to server, it doesnt work.

In any place i try to create a database, but it keeps me returning the following error: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

The only thing that i do is override the OnModelCreating method just to map my app.

Anyone has this error?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.1 CF: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584546/ef-4-1-cf-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a tutorial series that shows how to publish your Code First database and prevent Code First from trying to re-create the database in production, see 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider
The third tutorial in the series shows how to set up the Web.config file. The second shows how to deploy if you are using SQL Server Compact, the tenth shows how to deploy to full SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks... Using the tutorials I finally deployed my application. It was necessary to create a Db Initialize Strategy :).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to publish your database out to your hosting provider. Visual Studio has an easy way of doing this. In the server explorer tab, you can navigate to your database, right click and choose publish to provider. By doing this, you will not only export the scheme of your database, but you can also export out all data, stored procs, views etc.

You will need to adjust your code so that you are no longer trying to create a database on code run. Typically this approach is used for development, and you are no longer in development if you're moving to a hosting company. The changes may be in your global.asax, the dbcontext of your solution and any other place where you modified it to create the scheme for the database.

Hope this helps you some, and good luck on your project.